# Making my webpage to be compatible with browsers

Tags: javascript

I've actually tried getting my webpage to display the same way it does on Internet explorer like it does on Google Chrome by using these js codes but it seems not too work out
What should be done... I'll really appreciate an answer

````
let b_version=navigation.appVerse ;
let version=parseFloat(b_version);

document.write("Internet Explorer 8"+browser);
document.write(<br/>);
document.write("8.0.7601.17514" + version);```
````

Comment: "I've actually tried getting my webpage to display the same way it does on Internet explorer like it does on Google Chrome " <= Given that IE is out of support and is not being updated, and is being replaced with Edge, which is now turning into a reskinned Chrome...... why?

Comment: Are you using specific set pixels(px) for your size, assuming this is a window/size issue? Try using percentage (%) for your dimensions. Might be helpful to provide some more context on the issue. Perhaps share a couple screen shots of how it looks in both google chrome and internet explorer. Maybe include some of your css snippets too.

Comment: https://gs.statcounter.com/browser-market-share/all/united-states-of-america

Comment: Exactly, That's how I relate to this
Is the code in the page through the link going to help solve the issue @Taplar

Comment: How does that code in any way relate to making anything compatible?

Comment: I'm not sure you're understanding me.  I'm making a point that the marketshare for IE, a browser that is now no longer supported by Microsoft, is very very small.  So much so that, unless you work for a corporation that requires you to support it, putting a lot of effort into making it behave the same as other modern browsers will not net you the best return on investment.

Comment: Alright... I understand the point made

Comment: I'm beginning js and I wanted to make the display of my pages the same on both browsers by using a code I thought was helpful @connexo

Comment: There is no magic Javascript code that will do this for you. It's an extremely individual thing, which, depending on the size of your page, can take anything from 5 hours to months of work to achieve compatibility with old browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers have default designs for pages.
You can try resetting your CSS by giving all values a 0 on the **top of the CSS page** like this:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

This way no default styles will mess up your design.